# Trouble with calling a method

Tags: java

I am having trouble with calling a method in the main of my program.

The program specifications are as follows:

`setNoOfVehicles()`:  Returns the number of vehicles owned.

`setWeeklyFuelCost()`:  Returns the average weekly cost of gas for all vehicles owned.

`calcYearlyFuelCost()`:  Receives the average weekly fuel cost and returns the average annual fuel cost.

`displayFuelCost()`:  Receives the number of vehicles owned, the average weekly fuel cost, and the average annual fuel cost.

`main()`:

Calls `setWeeklyFuelCost()` and stores the returned value in a local variable.

Calls `displayFuelCost()` by sending it as arguments a call to `setNoOfVehicles()`, the local variable for the average weekly fuel cost, and a call to `calcYearlyFuelCost()`.

Scanner is declared at the global level

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

double x = setWeeklyFuelCost();

displayFuelCost( setNoOfVehicles(), x, calcYearlyFuelCost(x)); //This is the correct parameters I needed to pass thru displayFuelCost(). I didn't know this at the time and this is what I was trying to ask in this post.
}

private static int setNoOfVehicles()
{

System.out.print( "How many vehicles do I own?  " );
 int noOfVehicles = input.nextInt();
return noOfVehicles;
}

private static double setWeeklyFuelCost()
{


System.out.print( "Enter the average weekly fuel cost for my vehicles:  ");
double weeklyFuelCost = input.nextDouble();
return weeklyFuelCost;

}

private static double calcYearlyFuelCost(double weeklyFuelCost)
{

double yearlyFuelCost = 0.0;
yearlyFuelCost = weeklyFuelCost * 52;
return yearlyFuelCost;

}

private static void displayFuelCost( int noOfVehicles, double weeklyFuelCost, double yearlyFuelCost)
{
double difference = yearlyFuelCost - 5044.00;

if( yearlyFuelCost > 5044.00)
{
System.out.printf( "No of Vehicles:  %d\n"
                + "Avg Weekly Fuel Cost:  $%,.2f\n"
                + "Avg Annual Fuel Cost:  $%,.2f\n\n"
                + "I am OVER budget by $%,.2f.", noOfVehicles, weeklyFuelCost, yearlyFuelCost, difference);
}
else if( yearlyFuelCost < 5044.00)
{
difference = difference * -1;
System.out.printf( "No of Vehicles:  %d\n"
                + "Avg Weekly Fuel Cost:  $%,.2f\n"
                + "Avg Annual Fuel Cost:  $%,.2f\n\n"
                + "I am UNDER budget by $%,.2f.  PAARRTY!!! ", noOfVehicles, weeklyFuelCost, yearlyFuelCost, difference);
}
else
{
System.out.printf( "No of Vehicles:  %d\n"
                + "Avg Weekly Fuel Cost:  $%,.2f\n"
                + "Avg Annual Fuel Cost:  $%,.2f\n\n"
                + "I am RIGHT ON BUDGET!", noOfVehicles, weeklyFuelCost, yearlyFuelCost, difference);
}

}

}
```

The last specification is the one holding me up, call displayFuelCost()

My problem was that I didn't know exactly what parameters I needed to pass through `displayFuelCost()`. I knew I had to use the variable x above before asking this question.

`displayFuelCost( setNoOfVehicles(), x, calcYearlyFuelCost(x));` was all that I needed to input to get the main to work correctly.

Comment: What is the specific problem?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth -- He calls it but it won't come.

Comment: I think you have have confused _set_ ters with _get_ ters. Setters are supposed to change a variable and getters are supposed to return the value of a variable.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what I am suppose to code in the main for displayFuelCost(); I normally get the cannot be applied error from whatever I enter into the parameters.

Comment: @Jeffrey -- But in Java the distinction is purely formal -- there's no dependency in the language on method name.

Comment: Well, since `displayFuelCost` expects 3 parameters, I'd think you should pass it 3 parameters.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, but if the OP continues this practice, he will thoroughly confuse anyone else he programs with.

Comment: @Jeffrey -- That would be the least of the problems.

Comment: I finally figured it out, I knew I had to pass 3 variables, but I was having difficulty on the last parameter, I will update the above,

Answer (score 2):

You call a method `displayFuelCost()` which is not defined in your class. Instead you have a method

```
private static void displayFuelCost( int noOfVehicles, double weeklyFuelCost, double yearlyFuelCost) { ... }
```

that takes three parameters.

Change the method call to

```
displayFuelCost(1, 100.0, 5200.0);  // sample values
```

to eliminate the error and get some result.

Answer (score 1):

The code you pasted does not contain any class definition. If the main-method is in another class then the displayFuelCost-method, then you will have to change

```
private static void displayFuelCost( int noOfVehicles, double weeklyFuelCost, double yearlyFuelCost)
```

to public :

```
public static void displayFuelCost( int noOfVehicles, double weeklyFuelCost, double yearlyFuelCost)
```

That beeing said, I wouldn't recommend you this excessive usage of static methods. I don't see a reason why you shouldn't use proper object-oriented style (or at least a singleton-pattern, if it has to look static).

**//EDIT:**

The problem ist this part of your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

double x = setWeeklyFuelCost();

displayFuelCost(); //<-- need arguments here!
```

Inside your main function, you call the displayFuelCost-method, but do NOT provide the parameters it needs. When you have a look at the declaration of this method:

```
private static void displayFuelCost( int noOfVehicles, double weeklyFuelCost, double yearlyFuelCost)
```

}

You see that it needs 3 parameters: an integer, a double and another double. You have to provide them while calling the displayFuelCost function. For example like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

double x = setWeeklyFuelCost();

displayFuelCost(1, 2.5, 2.5); //<-- need parameters here!
```

}

**//EDIT 2:**

There are more problems in the whole code. I added an new answer concerning them.

Comment: I didn't paste that class definition since it has my name and exercise number. The main method is in this class. All the main is suppose to do is:

Calls setWeeklyFuelCost() and stores the returned value in a local variable and Calls displayFuelCost() by sending it as arguments a call to setNoOfVehicles(), the local variable for the average weekly fuel cost, and a call to calcYearlyFuelCost().

Comment: Dear Abweichung, I had a closer look at your code and I am afraid that you do not have the basic understanding you need to solve your problem! Even if you fix the particular bug you posted, the code will not do what you intend it to do. You have to have a look at the basics of Object-oriented design, otherwise you won't get far. For example, since you don't have any declared instance variables, you definitly can not set or get them.

Comment: displayFuelCost( setNoOfVehicles(), x, calcYearlyFuelCost(x)); has the code function to the specifications listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the code of the scanner and the class I can not prove that my solution works, you have to try it out:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int vehicleNumber = setNoOfVehicles();
        double costWeek = setWeeklyFuelCost();
        double costYear = calcYearlyFuelCost(costWeek);

        displayFuelCost(vehicleNumber, costWeek, costYear);
    }
// rest of your code
}
```

But once again I have to warn you, that this is probably NOT what your teacher wants you to deliver. He wants a class that instantiates itself  in the main method (e.g. Test test = new Test()) and than uses the instance-side methods (i.e. methods without static in the beginning) to fulfill the task. I would recommend you to try again. ;)